# Site posts and pages displayed instead of plugin template pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WP **"single_template"** & **"archive_template"** hooks for rendering plugin's own single and archive pages.

My plugin is OOP based. First, I added both filters in class constructor then my plugin users detected that their website posts and pages are displayed instead of plugin pages.

Here is the code:

```
  // Filter the Single Page Template
  add_filter( 'single_template', array( $this, 'get_single_template' ), 10 , 1 );

  // Filter the Archive Page Template
  add_filter( 'archive_template', array( $this, 'get_archive_template' ), 10 , 1 );
```

Then, I wrapped these filters into **"init"** hook, this issue reproduced.

Is this issue happening to due to other theme's/plugin's conflict or I am making any wrong call to these filters.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!